# react-native: create my own gradle build config

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I don't really know how to word this issue which is probably why i can't find any answers online.

in react-native we can do

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

and it will read `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and the `SigningConfig` in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
signingConfigs {
    release {            
        storeFile file(BLAH_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword BLAH_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias BLAH_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword BLAH_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD

    }
}
```

to produce a signed apk.

I'd like to create signed apks but using a different keystore file from a single command

so ideally

`./gradlew assembleDev`

and it would create an signed apk with a different output name and signed with a different key. Ideally with a different identifier so that the app can be installed side by side with the release version of the app.

I know i need to make changes to gradle config, but searching around i can't figure out how to do this. Is there a ready made tutorial that walks someone how to do this?

I'm thinking i can't possibly be the first person to want this.

Comment: You need to make 2 build using different package name, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `buildType` as the prefix for the property names

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
         release {
             storeFile file(property('release.storeFile'))
             storePassword property('release.storePassword')
             ...
         }
         dev {
             storeFile file(property('dev.storeFile'))
             storePassword property('dev.storePassword')
             ...
         }
    } 
    buildTypes {
        release { 
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ... 
        }
        dev { 
            signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so gradle will magically be able to translate `gradlew assembleDev` and know to use the dev keys from this?

Comment: I guess so. I've never used the android plugin but it would make sense to do it that way. I'm guessing android creates tasks for each `buildType` and respects the `signingConfig` for each.

Comment: is there any documentation that elaborates on this behavior you describe?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#gradle-sign) I've updated my answer accordingly